Deformation Retract (with regards to figure 8 and S1 (circle) )
I just learnt about deformation retracts. I feel like I am not able to visualize it properly. For example, I know that the fundamental group of figure 8 and circle are not isomorphic but I was still able to show a deformation retract (Hence the induced homomorphism with respect to the inclusion map is the isomorphism.) What's wrong with my reasoning (drawing)?


You're trying to move a circle through its "hole," but you cannot do that: A deformation retraction has to stay inside the circle at all times.

@BenSteffan Oh, yes. That was stupid of me. Thanks

The circle is a retraction of the figure-eight, but not a deformation retraction. There's no way to continuously shrink a circle to a single point in the way that you sketched - the circle is not contractible.
